Next js revalidatePath with server actions redirect to home page and reset previous component state
The problem:
Next.js revalidatePath on specific url doesn't work as I expected. I'm trying to build a page for inquiries. The user will be able to view a list of inquiries and edit them using an edit dialog.
I'm trying to add comment, then I want to view the new comment inside the comment-list component with the dialog open.
for example:
I have the following components

Topic-Editor-Dialog - a dialog to edit specific topic in an inquiry.

Topic-Editor-Form - form to update inquiry topic.

Inquiry-Topic-Comment-List - list of comments.
Topic-Editor-Create-Comment-Form - form to create new comment.





My problem is when I'm using server action inside the create comment form and revalidate the path, for example revalidatePath('/inquiries/{some-random-inquiryId}') I'm getting redirected to '/'.
Why am I getting redirect to '/' ?
Is there a way to use server actions and keep previous state?
Does server action support this behaivor? Is it possible to revalidatePath with server actions and remember state of not default state(like dialog visibility/ a select option which is not the default one)?
if not, the solutions for that is to move from server actions to api routes?
or not using dialog for editing and keeping state and build edit pages for that?
Thanks

Please share any relevant parts of your code. This is very difficult to debug without being able to see how and where you're calling revalidatePath.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
